# Extract version from string cross platform

Tags: sed, grep

I need to create a line in makefile which will extract the version from string, and will work cross-platform, ideally without dependencies.

This is what I had

```
echo "golangci-lint has version 1.42.0 built..." | grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d'

retuslt: 1.42.0
```

But it doesn't work on mac.

Trying to do it with sed like this, but doesn't work

```
echo "golangci-lint has version 1.42.0 built ..." | sed -n  's/.*\(\d+\.\d+\.\d\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: You need to install `pcregrep` and use it with `-o` option and your pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without dependencies? I think sed is an option

Comment: Is there a single match on the line?

Comment: Yes, only single match

Comment: Then use `sed -En  's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/p'`

Comment: cool, it works! Does sed not support \d?

Comment: No, `sed` does not support `\d` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
grep -ow '[0-9][0-9.]\+[0-9]'
```

That uses only a basic regular expression, and options that  BSD grep and GNU grep share.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
echo "golangci-lint has version 1.42.0 built ..." | sed -En  's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enables the POSIX ERE syntax
- `n` - default line output is suppressed now
- `.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*` - any text, then Group 1 capturing one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits and the rest of the line
- `\1` - the replacement is just Group 1 value
- `p` - only the substitution result is printed.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, you could try following `awk` program which will print only matched value of version out of whole line.

```
echo "golangci-lint has version 1.42.0 built ..." | 
awk '
{
  match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, printing line's value with `echo` command of shell here and sending its output as a standard input to `awk` code, where using `match` function to match mentioned regex in it. If there is a match then printing matched value.

***Explanation of regex:***

`[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`: Matching 1 or more occurrences of digits followed by `.` followed by 1 or more occurrences of digits followed by another dot`.` followed by 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

`-P` is an experimental feature in `gnu-grep` which is not available on Mac BSD. However default `grep` available in Mac can handle it easily with `-E` switch but you have to use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` in place of `\d` in your search pattern:

```sh
s="golangci-lint has version 1.42.0 built..."
grep -Eo '([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+' <<< "$s"

# or else
grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]+\.)+[[:digit:]]+' <<< "$s"

1.42.0
```

As a side note I have gnu-grep installed on my Mac using `home brew` package.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting the following:

```
echo "golangci-lint has version 1.42.0 built..." | grep -o '[0-9\.]\{4,\}'
```

***Explanation***

[0-9\.] --- match a single digit or dot(.)

\{4,\}  --- the matched charterer 4 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

This awk is 100% POSIX:

```
awk 'match($0, /[0-9][0-9.]+[0-9]/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

It will always print the first match and only (up to) one match per line. There can be zero or more dots in the number, but leading/trailing dots won't get printed.

`grep -o` is quite portable, but not every platform supported by Go has it. Eg. IBM AIX. Also note that if a line has multiple matches, it will print each match on a new line.